# How to move an icon to the upper-right hand side?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, icons

I'm trying to create an icon on the upper-right hand side in android studio which is besides the **claims** word. It should look like the image below:

[image]

**Claims1.java**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        fk = bundle.getLong("ab");
        View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claims, container, false);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)claims.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar myActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(myActionBar.getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.create);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        myActionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
        return claims;
    }
```

**claims.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/create" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

However I only able to get this.

[image]

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: [Menus in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) - this image is intended to be an ActionBar menu icon.

Comment: @PPartisan Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Add

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in `OnCreate` method in your `Fragment`.

**2.** Create `my_menu.xml` under `\res\menu` with your menu

```
      <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
          <item
              android:icon="@drawable/YOURICONHERE"
              android:id="@+id/YOURIDHERE"
              android:orderInCategory="100"
              android:title="YOURTITLE"
              app:showAsAction="always" />
      </menu>
```

**3.** `Override` method `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
     @Override
     public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
         //Do what you want with menu - listeners etc.
     }
```

Comment: menu item should specify a title